# MongoDB change order of array in document

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

so here is my current data structure:

```
[parents] => Array (
[0] => Array (
    [title] => Test 1
)
[1] => Array (
    [title] => Test 2
)
)
```

I want to add a new array to the BEGINNING of this, so array[0] would become array[1] (shown below)

```
    [parents] => Array (
[0] => Array (
    [title] => Test 3
)
[1] => Array (
    [title] => Test 1
)
[2] => Array (
    [title] => Test 2
)
)
```

I need to update multiple documents at once, so I don't want to individually run an update command on each document within a loop. Any ideas how to tackle this?

Answer (score 2):

[Just fetch data from mongo by natural order](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sorting+and+Natural+Order)

```
$cursor = $p->find($range,$co)->sort(array('$natural' => -1) );
```

Comment: would you then resave it into the database.

Comment: I understand how to sort in natural order; I want to PREPEND an array into the parent array. Is there any way I can do this without finding it, modifying it and then saving it? Is there any sort of update query I can use??

Comment: Oops, sorry Wojons! Didn't see you had posted basically the same thing as me :)

Comment: Mongodb not suport even autoicrement so need make spageti code

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible at the moment since the server doesn't support it yet. Please watch for

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2191

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2036